# How do I configure npm packages using a package list? Like Bower

Tags: npm, bower

I'm a big fan of bower. I don't need to put a stack of packages in my repository, I just commit bower.json each time and I'm done.

So my question really is, can I make npm read from a json file in the same way that bower does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm has [package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html). This file has dependencies and devDependencies parts. You can use this file similar to bower.json.

```
npm install
```

will install necessary dependencies to your project's node_modules directory. 
See sample package.json below.

```
{
  "name": "SampleMobileApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Sample App",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.3",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-bowercopy": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-phonegap": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "grunt",
    "javascript"
  ],
  "author": "Atilla Ozgur",
  "license": "MIT",
}
```

dependencies are your runtime dependencies that your users need to download while devDependencies are your developer dependencies like your test runtime, grunt helper packages etc.

Comment: Thank you. It was impossble to infer this from their website. Whoever did the website for bower should go and do the same for npm.

Comment: @tomwrong If I answered your question, please accept it.

Comment: thanks for that ;-). Also, the more I looked into it, the more I suspect that bower were 'copying' (I mean that in good way) npm.